# Iniciar meu aplicativo com Windows em System Tray

Tags: java, windows, system-tray

Não tenho ideia de como eu faço meu aplicativo iniciar com Windows 7 já em modo de *System Tray*. Ou seja, iniciar com Windows e ficar o ícone do programa ao lado do relógio do Windows 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basicamente o que você deve fazer é pegar a instância do `SystemTray` do seu sistema operacional e adicionar um novo objeto do tipo `TrayIcon` personalizado a ele.

O `TrayIcon` é o objeto que você vai trabalhar em cima. Após criado, adicione uma uma imagem a ele, geralmente também é adicionado um menu para que haja uma interface com o usuário.

Para criar esse menu você deve criar um `PopupMenu` e adicionar um `MenuItem` dentro dele com as opções que desejar.

Exemplo:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class MeuTray {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
          SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
          Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("imagem.gif");
          PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
          MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Um MenuItem");
          popup.add(item);
          TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Texto de dica", popup);
          trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true); 
          try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
          } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.err.println("Não pode adicionar a tray");
          }
        } else {
          System.err.println("Tray indisponível");
        }
      }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
  }
}
```

Resultado:

Usando a seguinte imagem como ícone:

[image: imagem icone]

Passando o mouse sobre o ícone:

[image: mouse over]

Clicando com o botão direito do mouse no ícone:

[image: clicando no tray]

Adicione mais opções no seu MenuItem e trate os eventos quando o usuário selecionar o item do MenuItem.

Fontes:
[Java Tutorials - How to Use the System Tray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)
[Oracle Tech Tips - Getting to Know System Tray](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/getting_to_know_system_tray)

Comment: Seria possível colocar a funcionalidade de quando clicar com a direita do mouse no icone do System Tray abrir um menu?

Comment: @JúniorNascimento sim, veja a última imagem, já está fazendo isso >> "Um MenuItem"

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!! mais tarde eu testo. Parabéns pelo seu nível de conhecimento! :D

Comment: @JúniorNascimento obrigado =) Apesar de você não ter testado te garanto que funciona, eu testei esse código daí para gerar as imagens. Se surgirem dúvidas enquanto implementa esse código não se desespere, acontece, mas tenho certeza que você vai implementar também.

Comment: Obrigado. Tenho gostado muito de Java. Retorno sim se precisar. Ah! Obrigado também pela atenção! Abraço!

Comment: Math, como eu faço para dicionar um novo item no menu? Por exmeplo "Abrir" e "Sair" no System Tray?

Comment: @JúniorNascimento só agora vi sua mensagem. Acabei de ver que você adicionou mais informações aqui no mesmo tópico, entretanto o certo seria você criar um nova pergunta, pois o espaço abaixo da pergunta é apenas para respostas. Poderia criar uma nova pergunta com o conteúdo que você colocou aqui embaixo?

Comment: Teria como esconder a janela do console e ficar apenas com o Tray?

Comment: @LucasTorres olá, acredito que sim, mas eu teria que fazer uns testes, vi que você criou uma nova pergunta, acho que será mais fácil conseguir a resposta assim, vou tentar elaborar algo aqui.

Comment: @LucasTorres rodando o código da minha resposta não é aberta nenhuma janela nova, apenas a do prompt de comando se mantém aberta, se deseja poder fechá-la sem matar o programa rode com o javaw, acho que isso é tudo que você precisa.

Comment: @Math vou especificar na outra pergunta como estou rodando ele, ok?

Comment: @LucasTorres ok