# Minimizar + SytemTray

Tags: java, swing

Gente estou querendo que ao clicar para minimizar o programa, o ícone dele fique ao lado do relógio. Eu criei um botão que faz essa ação. Confesso que não foi eu que fiz, mas o autor me ajudou muito.

Esse é código que estou usando no botão.
Queria que pudesse fazer o mesmo mimizando o programa pra ficar ao lado do relógio sem precisar clicar no botão que criei.

Agradeço desde já!

```
if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
    final SystemTray systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(new ImageIcon(icoPath, "omt").getImage(), "QuickStage");
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);// Autosize icon base on space

    // Mouse
    MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {

        // Exibir
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            systemTray.remove(trayIcon);
            main.this.setVisible(true);
        }
    };

    // Ocultar
    trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
    try {
        systemTray.add(trayIcon);
        main.this.setVisible(false);
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Aviso!", "QuickStage continua em execução...", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Iniciar meu aplicativo com Windows em System Tray](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15553/3117)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resposta já está no seu código. Para ficar mais fácil, vamos reorganizá-la:

```
public void moveToTray() {
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) return;
    final SystemTray systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(new ImageIcon(icoPath, "omt").getImage(), "QuickStage");
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);// Autosize icon base on space

    // Mouse
    MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {

        // Exibir
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            systemTray.remove(trayIcon);
            main.this.setVisible(true);
        }
    };

    // Ocultar
    trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
    try {
        systemTray.add(trayIcon);
        main.this.setVisible(false);
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Aviso!", "QuickStage continua em execução...", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Com isso, basta chamar o método `moveToTray()` sempre que você quiser minimizar o programa no *tray*, inclusive no código do seu botão:

```
botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        moveToTray();
    }
});
```

Ou então, se você tiver o java 8:

```
botao.addActionListener(e -> moveToTray());
```

Comment: Boa noite... Estou tentando de todas a formas implementar um TrayIcon... Funciona perfeitamente este exemplo, mas não sei o que to fazendo que minha imagem não aparece. Fica um espaço vazio, mostra a mensagem e também o aviso quando coloca o mouse encima mas a imagem não aparece. Já passou por isso? Poderia me ajudar? A imagem eu coloquei "JPG,PNG,GIF,..." O tamanho esta 16X16 px.

Comment: @Valdecir Sugiro que crie uma nova pergunta para isso, incluindo todo o código-fonte pertinente que você tiver.