# Tray Icon Windows

Tags: java, ícone-de-bandeja

Estou criando uma aplicação para realizar backup, e penso em colocar a aplicação para roda em tempo integral em que a máquina esteja em funcionamento.

Penso colocar a aplicação no Try Icon do Windows porém depois de alguns testes consegui fazer o funcionar só que ao minimizar a aplicação não consigo somente mantê-la minimizada no tray, e fica na barra de tarefa.

O post que segui para criar meu tray foi o do meu link a seguir:

[Post Tray Icon](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15553/iniciar-meu-aplicativo-com-windows-em-system-tray)

Comment: `só que ao minimizar a aplicação não consigo somente mantê-la no minimizada no tray` O que você quer dizer com isso? Que o ícone ainda fica na barra de tarefas?

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Sim isso mesmo arrumei a pergunta.

Comment: Está usando `swing` ou `awt`?

Comment: @JéfersonBueno estou usando swing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu encontrei duas formas de fazer o que você precisa.

Uma delas é *settar* o tipo do seu `JFrame` para `JFrame.Type.UTILITY`.
**Obs:** Você só pode mudar o tipo do `JFrame` enquanto ele ainda não está visível.
**Obs2:** Eu testei com o *JDK 1.7*, não sei existe o método `.setType()` para versões inferiores.

O que eu fiz foi

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(100, 100);
frame.setLocation(100, 150);
frame.setType(JFrame.Type.UTILITY); //Essa é a parte importante
frame.setVisible(true); //Note que eu só deixei o frame visível após usar o setType()
```

Para aplicar isso ao seu caso, será necessário usar o evento `setType()` sempre que você minimizar ou maximizar a janela, para tirá-lo e colocá-lo na `TaskBar` do Windows, respectivamente. Para isso você pode usar o método [`windowStateChanged()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html), provável que você já esteja usando-o para colocar o ícone na *Tray Icon*.

[Documentação do método `setType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setType(java.awt.Window.Type))
[Documentação do `Enum Window.Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.Type.html)

A outra solução eu encontrei no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461477/how-to-hide-a-jframe-in-system-tray-of-taskbar), é bem fácil de entender o que o código faz. Além de ter o que você precisa, ainda tem um menu `popup` no ícone que fica *Tray*. Segue o abaixo o código original.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Mohammad Faisal
 * ermohammadfaisal.blogspot.com
 * facebook.com/m.faisal6621
 *
 */

public class HideToSystemTray extends JFrame{
    TrayIcon trayIcon;
    SystemTray tray;
    HideToSystemTray(){
        super("SystemTray test");
        System.out.println("creating instance");
        try{
            System.out.println("setting look and feel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Unable to set LookAndFeel");
        }

        if(SystemTray.isSupported()){
            System.out.println("system tray supported");
            tray=SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/media/faisal/DukeImg/Duke256.png");
            ActionListener exitListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Exiting....");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            };

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
            MenuItem defaultItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
            defaultItem.addActionListener(exitListener);
            popup.add(defaultItem);
            defaultItem = new MenuItem("Open");

            defaultItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setVisible(true);
                    setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
            });

            popup.add(defaultItem);
            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "SystemTray Demo", popup);
            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        }else{
            System.out.println("system tray not supported");
        }

        addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                if(e.getNewState() == ICONIFIED){
                    try {
                        tray.add(trayIcon);
                        setVisible(false);
                        System.out.println("added to SystemTray");
                    } catch (AWTException ex) {
                        System.out.println("unable to add to tray");
                    }
                }
        if(e.getNewState()==7){
                    try{
            tray.add(trayIcon);
            setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("added to SystemTray");
            }catch(AWTException ex){
                System.out.println("unable to add to system tray");
            }
        }
        if(e.getNewState()==MAXIMIZED_BOTH){
                    tray.remove(trayIcon);
                    setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("Tray icon removed");
                }
                if(e.getNewState()==NORMAL){
                    tray.remove(trayIcon);
                    setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("Tray icon removed");
                }
            }
        });

        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Duke256.png"));

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new HideToSystemTray();
    }
}
```